# How to create a new ribbon button? SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, xml

I have the following code which creates for me a custom tab, custom group and a custom button called `Skills`, but how Can I create a new button called `Education`? in same group but with different `CommandAction`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <CustomAction
     Id="CustomRibbonTab"
     Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
     RegistrationId="0x01040004DF150B6311CB4D8A33D0764922EDF6"  
     RegistrationType="ContentType">
     <CommandUIExtension>
       <CommandUIDefinitions>
         <CommandUIDefinition
           Location="Ribbon.Tabs._children">
           <Tab
            Id="Ribbon.CustomTab1"
            Title="Skills"
            Description="skills Tab !!!"
            Sequence="501">
             <Scaling
               Id="Ribbon.CustomTab1.Scaling">
               <MaxSize
                 Id="Ribbon.CustomTab1.MaxSize"
                 GroupId="Ribbon.CustomTab1.CustomGroup"
                 Size="OneLargeTwoMedium"/>
               <Scale
                 Id="Ribbon.CustomTab1.Scaling.CustomTabScaling"
                 GroupId="Ribbon.CustomTab1.CustomGroup"
                 Size="OneLargeTwoMedium" />
             </Scaling>
             <Groups Id="Ribbon.CustomTab1.Groups">
               <Group
                 Id="Ribbon.CustomTab1.CustomGroup"
                 Description="Custom Group!"
                 Title="Custom Group"
                 Sequence="52"
                 Template="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplate">
                 <Controls Id="Ribbon.CustomTab1.CustomGroup.Controls">
                   <Button
                     Id="Skillsbutton"
                     Command="CustomTab.CustomButtonCommand"
                     Sequence="15"
                     Description=""
                     LabelText="Skills"
                     Image32by32="/_layouts/images/PPEOPLE.GIF"
                     TemplateAlias="cust1"/>
                 </Controls>
               </Group>
             </Groups>
           </Tab>
         </CommandUIDefinition>
         <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
           <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplate">
             <Layout
               Title="OneLargeTwoMedium"
               LayoutTitle="OneLargeTwoMedium">
               <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow">
                 <Row>
                   <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="cust1" />
                 </Row>
               </Section>
             </Layout>
           </GroupTemplate>
         </CommandUIDefinition>
       </CommandUIDefinitions>
       <CommandUIHandlers>
         <CommandUIHandler
           Command="CustomTab.CustomButtonCommand"
            CommandAction="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog('http://london/SitePages/empl.aspx');" />
       </CommandUIHandlers>
     </CommandUIExtension>
   </CustomAction>
 </Elements>
```

I tried to add a new button but everything messed up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually very simple! :)
You only have to duplicate the `<Button` tag and the `<CommandUIHandler` tag. 
Also be sure to duplicate the `<ControlRef` in the `<Layout`, or else the new button will not show. 
Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <CustomAction
     Id="CustomRibbonTab"
     Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
     RegistrationId="0x01040004DF150B6311CB4D8A33D0764922EDF6"  
     RegistrationType="ContentType">
     <CommandUIExtension>
       <CommandUIDefinitions>
         <CommandUIDefinition
           Location="Ribbon.Tabs._children">
           <Tab
            Id="Ribbon.CustomTab1"
            Title="Skills"
            Description="skills Tab !!!"
            Sequence="501">
             <Scaling
               Id="Ribbon.CustomTab1.Scaling">
               <MaxSize
                 Id="Ribbon.CustomTab1.MaxSize"
                 GroupId="Ribbon.CustomTab1.CustomGroup"
                 Size="OneLargeTwoMedium"/>
               <Scale
                 Id="Ribbon.CustomTab1.Scaling.CustomTabScaling"
                 GroupId="Ribbon.CustomTab1.CustomGroup"
                 Size="OneLargeTwoMedium" />
             </Scaling>
             <Groups Id="Ribbon.CustomTab1.Groups">
               <Group
                 Id="Ribbon.CustomTab1.CustomGroup"
                 Description="Custom Group!"
                 Title="Custom Group"
                 Sequence="52"
                 Template="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplate">
                 <Controls Id="Ribbon.CustomTab1.CustomGroup.Controls">
                   <Button
                     Id="Skillsbutton"
                     Command="CustomTab.CustomButtonCommand"
                     Sequence="15"
                     Description=""
                     LabelText="Skills"
                     Image32by32="/_layouts/images/PPEOPLE.GIF"
                     TemplateAlias="cust1"/>
                   <Button
                     Id="Educationbutton"
                     Command="CustomTab.EducationButtonCommand"
                     Sequence="16"
                     Description=""
                     LabelText="Education"
                     Image32by32="/_layouts/images/Education.GIF"
                     TemplateAlias="cust2"/>
                 </Controls>
               </Group>
             </Groups>
           </Tab>
         </CommandUIDefinition>
         <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
           <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplate">
             <Layout
               Title="OneLargeTwoMedium"
               LayoutTitle="OneLargeTwoMedium">
               <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow">
                 <Row>
                   <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="cust1" />
                   <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="cust2" />
                 </Row>
               </Section>
             </Layout>
           </GroupTemplate>
         </CommandUIDefinition>
       </CommandUIDefinitions>
       <CommandUIHandlers>
         <CommandUIHandler
           Command="CustomTab.CustomButtonCommand"
            CommandAction="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog('http://london/SitePages/empl.aspx');" />
         <CommandUIHandler
           Command="CustomTab.EducationButtonCommand"
            CommandAction="__todo: your action here__" />
       </CommandUIHandlers>
     </CommandUIExtension>
   </CustomAction>
 </Elements>
```

Comment: now it is not displaying any button,  both of skills and education button disappeared. Why?

Comment: Did you use the exact code above? Did you replace the _todo_ `CommandAction`? It's most probably a syntax error somewhere in the XML. The concept is correct (I use it all the time).

Comment: yes I replaced `CommandAction` with my own javascript

Comment: The Layout has only one ControlRef. Don't you need two to make the button show? With different `TemplateAlias' ?

Comment: Yes @Nils now I am seeing 2 buttons working perfect, but I am facing problems with groups I cannot create 2 groups, how to do that?

Comment: You'll need to add a new `Group` with  a new `Id`. Then you'll need to duplicate `MaxSize` and `Scale` and modify their `GroupId` accordingly. I think you can re-use the `Template` - no need to copy it.